# Install EXM on Azure

Tags: azure, exm, paas

I am trying to install Sitecore on Azure using marketplace XP1 template also I need to install EXM, in installation wizard I select Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and EXM module, when I try to open content delivery or content management portal I receive  error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

detailed error :
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

I notice when we provision Sitecore XP1 alone without EXM the CM and CD working fine, can you please help

Comment: Do you see any relevant errors in the Sitecore log?

Answer (score 1):

To install EXM to Azure PaaS please use the ARM templates from GitHub:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/EXM%203.5.0

and the web deploy packages:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/35/Email_Experience_Manager_35_Update1.aspx

**Packages for EXM0 configuration** 
Web deploy packages for EXM0/Single instance configuration on Azure AppService.

**Packages for EXM1 configuration** 
Web deploy packages for EXM1 configuration on Azure App Services. The packages contains 5 server roles: Content Management, Content Delivery, Analytics Processing, Email Processing and Reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating both installs. Go for Sitecore 8.2 first using Azure templates. Once you have ensured that your SXP platform is working as expected, [download EXM packages](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager.aspx) specific to your requirement. Then use Sitecore installation wizard on CM server to complete EXM install. Make sure to complete all required pre and post installation steps.